# How to create rectangle background slightly bend from one side

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Hi I want to draw a slightly bend divider line between two horizontally placed textview. I don't want to put any type of image in background. I have tried using xml drawable but my code doesn't work .

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="40dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
</shape>
</item>

<item
android:right="100dp"
android:left="-180dp"
android:top="-25dp"
android:bottom="-42dp">
<rotate
android:fromDegrees="15">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
</rotate>
</item>
```

I want to design the layout showing in image.

Comment: check my edited answer

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan Thanks, It worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You could create `VectorDrawable` in this case. Note that in the pre-lollipop versions the images would be generated anyway, otherwise use `srcCompat`.

Your vector drawable could look like this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="36dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="36.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF0"
    android:pathData="M0,0 L0,24 L20,24 L36,0 L0,0 Z"/>
```

[image]

To provide more accuracy according to your needs you should edit it yourself

More [about vectors](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html)
[Simple start](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/understanding-vectordrawable-pathdata-commands-in-android-d56a6054610e?source=user_profile---------1-)

Comment: Thanks I'll try this one

Answer (score 1):

You can create that shape like this way

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"

    >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/banner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TADAA!!!"

            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/myshape"
            />



</LinearLayout>
```

myshape.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="40dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ff0" />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item
        android:right="100dp"
        android:left="100dp"
        android:top="-100dp"
        android:bottom="-100dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>


    <item
        android:right="-100dp"
        android:left="100dp"
        android:top="-100dp"
        android:bottom="-100dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this vector drawable in xml file

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="99.0"
    android:viewportWidth="338.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M0,45.5l0,40.5 163.5,0 163.5,0 0,-40.5 0,-40.5 -163.5,0 -163.5,0 0,40.5zM176,10.6c0,0.3 -10.6,16.3 -23.5,35.5l-23.6,34.9 -61.9,0 -62,0 0,-35.5 0,-35.5 85.5,0c47,0 85.5,0.3 85.5,0.6zM322,45.5l0,35.5 -93.5,0 -93.6,0 18.7,-27.8c10.3,-15.2 21.2,-31.2 24.1,-35.5l5.4,-7.7 69.5,0 69.4,0 0,35.5z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" />
</vector>
```